# EC2 backend docker run issues after ssh into instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker

Im attempting to bring up the backend on this Ruby on Rails app using docker but am getting the following error after I try to run the following commands on my ssh'd ec2 instance.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-3-155 ~]$ docker run --rm \
>-it --name *****-db-setup \
>839014*****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/*****-backend:dev-latest \
>bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate

rake aborted!

 PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db"
       to address: Name or service not known
       /usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
       /usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
       /usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
       /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:695:in
       `connect'
       /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:220:in
       `initialize'
       /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `new'
       /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `postgresql_connection' /myapp/app/models/admin.rb:7:in `include'
       /myapp/app/models/admin.rb:7:in `<class:Admin>'
       /myapp/app/models/admin.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
       /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in
       `load' .......Tasks: TOP => db:drop =>
       db:check_protected_environments => environment
```

this is my env file I created

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***********
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=***************************
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
$ export DB_USER=*****
$ export DB_PASS=****test1
$ export DB_NAME=*****_backend
$ export DB_HOST=tf-*****-backend-2021051***********.c8o12l*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
$ export DB_PORT=5432
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres
      backend:
        build: backend
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/38732187/42559
        entrypoint: /myapp/entrypoint.sh
        command: bundle exec unicorn -p 3001
        volumes:
          - ./backend/:/myapp
        ports:
          - "3001:3001"
        depends_on:
          - db
        env_file:
          - ./.env
      frontend:
        build: frontend
        command: yarn server
        volumes:
          - ./frontend/:/app
          - /app/node_modules
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
          - backend
```

This is the Database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_HOST") { "db" } %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_USER") { "postgres" } %>
  port: <%= ENV["DB_PORT"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["DB_PASS"] %>
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: backend_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: backend_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV["DB_NAME"] %>
```

From my observations and attempts I believe it due to how the Docker-compose.yml and env file are interacting or something with my ruby server. I already have the backend image in the EC2 instance repository, now im trying to convert it to a container and bring up the backend. Thanks for any insight provided in advance !